# Array populated from Firebase returned empty, but data was retrieved. Why?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Still learning some swift and managed to advance and retrieving data from a firestore database. I have a `Data Controller` whose task is to offload all the data retrieving from firestore. It does the calls and gets data, but when returning the info from the first function I have implemented on it, it's empty.

Here's an example of the funcion:

```
func fetchUnidades(for foo: MyFirstEnum, and bar: MySecondEnum ) -> [MyClassType]{
    
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let colPath = "my/firebase/path"
    let results = [MyClassType]()
    let collection = db.collection(colPath)
    
    collection.whereField("myField", isEqualTo: foo.rawValue).getDocuments() { querySnapshot, err in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                do {
                    print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())") // 1st print
                    let newMyClass = try document.data(as: MyClassType.self)
                    results.append(newMyClass)
                    print("here") // 2nd print - debug breakpoint
                }catch (let error) {
                    print("\(error)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    print("DC - Recovered \(results.count) results")
    return results
}
```

Assume `MyFirstEnum`, `MySecondEnum` and `MyClassType` are correct, because the database retrieves info. On the `1st print` line, there's output for data retrieved, and on the `2nd print - debug breakpoint` line, if I do a po results, it has one value, which is the one retrieved as you can see here:

[image: PO output of the item loaded from the Firestore database]

`unidades` being the name on my code of `results` on this example.

But right after continuing with the execution, `unidades`, aka `results` is empty, the line:
`print("DC - Recovered \(results.count) results")`
prints `DC - Recovered 0 results` and the return also returns an empty array with zero values on it.

Any idea about why this might be happening? And how to solve the issue? Obviously the goal is to return the info...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the result comes asynchronously. Your `fetchUnidades` returns `results` array before it's populated.

You need to add a `completion` closure in this case. Instead of returning `results` you call that `completion` closure and pass the `results` as its argument.

```
func fetchUnidades(for foo: MyFirstEnum, and bar: MySecondEnum, completion: (results: [MyClassType]?, error: Error?) -> Void) {
let db = Firestore.firestore()
let colPath = "my/firebase/path"
let collection = db.collection(colPath)

collection.whereField("myField", isEqualTo: foo.rawValue).getDocuments() { querySnapshot, err in
    if let err = err {
        print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        completion(nil, err)
    } else {
       let results = [MyClassType]()
       for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
            do {
                print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())") // 1st print
                let newMyClass = try document.data(as: MyClassType.self)
                results.append(newMyClass)
                print("here") // 2nd print - debug breakpoint
            }catch (let error) {
                print("\(error)")
            }
        }
        completion(results, nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is it shown as 1 element then? And, how can I fix this behavior?

Comment: That one element is because when you hit a breakpoint and then continue execution the array may had already one item inserted.

Comment: Still not working... the completion handler is called as a closure when calling the function somewhere else in the program, `dc.fetchUnidades(for foo: MyFirstEnum.case1, and bar: MySecondEnum.case1) { results in recovered = results}` and the results array comes up empty.

Comment: Nevermind, it works well, I was just placing the `completion` call on the wrong place. Thanks!

Comment: Good to see you figured it out. If you want you can utilize [async/await](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/swift/5.5/async-await) for your code to look like synchronous which is more readable.

Comment: Got an example of async await I could use?